# Clisp error : Variable has no value (In this Binary search program high and low has no value)

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, slime

Simple program for binary search.

1. elements contain no. of elements
2. then array contains those elements
3. then q contains no. of queries
4. search contains element to be searched.

Why this error is coming about high and low has no value after some iterations.
Kindly help :)

My Code :-

```
(setf elements (parse-integer (read-line)))
(setf array (make-array elements :fill-pointer 0))
(dotimes (i elements) (vector-push (parse-integer (read-line)) array))
(setf q (parse-integer (read-line)))


(defvar *mid*)
(dotimes (i q)
  (setf search (parse-integer (read-line)))

(do ((low 0)
     (high (- elements 1))
     (mid (floor (+ low high) 2)
          (floor (+ low high) 2)))
    ((>= low high) (setf *mid* nil))
  (cond
     ((eql (elt array mid) search) (setf *mid* mid))
     ((< (elt array mid) search) (setf high (- mid 1)))
     (t (setf low (+ mid 1)))))
  (format t "~a" *mid*))
```

Comment: You should define all global variables using `defvar` in advance and check the advices regarding code formatting given here on a regular basis. I think there is a bug in the `cond` statement. You miss to quit the `do` loop if `search` is found. And try `do*` instead of `do`.

Comment: If you need further help please provide a minimal example using fixed test data and the exact output which shows the error.

Comment: Thank You !! Now its working did all the things you said .

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a fine example of an [old adage](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html):

> the determined Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language.

Unfortunately Lisp programmers are generally quiche-eating hippies: so here is one quiche-eater's solution to this problem, using notions not present when FORTRAN IV was handed down to us from above on punched stones.  These notions are therefore clearly heretical, but nonetheless useful.

Assuming this is homework, you probably will not be able to submit this answer.

### Reading the data

First of all we'll write some functions which read the specification of the problem from a stream or file.  I have inferred what it is from your code.

```
(defun stream->search-spec (stream)
  ;; Read a search vector from a stream: return a vector to be searched
  ;; and a vector of elements to search for.
  ;;
  ;; This function defines what is in files: each line contains an
  ;; integer, and the file contains a count followed by that many
  ;; lines, which specifies first the vector to be searched, and then
  ;; the things to search for.
  ;;
  ;; This relies on PARSE-INTEGER & READ-LINE to puke appropriately.
  (flet ((read-vector ()
           (let* ((elts (parse-integer (read-line stream)))
                  (vec (make-array elts :element-type 'integer))) ;won't help
             (dotimes (i elts vec)
               (setf (aref vec i) (parse-integer (read-line stream)))))))
    (values (read-vector) (read-vector))))

(defun file->search-spec (file)
  ;; Read a search vector from a file.  This is unused below but is
  ;; useful to have.
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (stream->search-spec in)))

(defun validate-sorted-vector (v)
  ;; check that V is a sorted vector
  (dotimes (i (- (length v) 1) v)
    (unless (<= (aref v i) (aref v (1+ i)))
      (return-from validate-sorted-vector nil))))
```

The last function is used below to sanity check the data, since the search algorithm assumes the vector is sorted.

### The search function

This implements binary search in the same way yours tries to do.  Rather than doing it with loops and explicit assignemnt it does it using a local recursive function, which is far easier to understand.  There are also various sanity checks and optionally debugging output. In any implementation which optimises tail calls this will be optimised to a loop; in implementations which don't then there will be a few extra function calls but stack overflow problems are very unlikely (think about why: how big would the vector need to be?).

```
(defun search-sorted-vector-for (vector for &key (debug nil))
  ;; search a sorted vector for some value.  If DEBUG is true then
  ;; print what we're doing.  Return the index, or NIL if FOR is not
  ;; present.
  (when debug
    (format *debug-io* "~&* ~D:~%" for))
  (labels ((search (low mid high)
             (when debug
               (format *debug-io* "~& ~10D ~10D ~10D~%" low mid high))
             (if (<= low mid high)
                 ;; more to do
                 (let ((candidate (aref vector mid)))
                   (cond ((= candidate for)
                          ;; found it
                          mid)
                         ((< candidate for)
                          ;; look higher
                          (search (1+ mid) (floor (+ high mid 1) 2) high))
                         ((> candidate for)
                          ;; look lower
                          (search low (floor (+ low mid) 2) (1- mid)))
                         (t
                          ;; can't happen
                          (error "mutant death"))))
               ;; low = high: failed
               nil)))
    (let ((high (1- (length vector))))
      (search 0 (floor high 2) high))))
```

### Putting the previous two things together.

`search-sorted-vector-with-search-vector` will repeatedly search using the two vectors that the `*->search-spec` functions return.  `stream->search-results` uses `stream->search-spec` and then calls this on its values.  `file->search-results` does it all from a file.

```
(defun search-sorted-vector-with-search-vector (vector searches &key (debug nil))
  ;; do a bunch of searches, returning a vector of results.
  (let ((results (make-array (length searches))))
    (dotimes (i (length searches) results)
      (setf (aref results i) (search-sorted-vector vector (aref searches i)
                                                   :debug debug)))))

(defun stream->search-results (stream &key (debug nil))
  ;; Read search specs from a stream, and search according to them.
  ;; Return the vector of results, the vector being searched and the
  ;; vector of search specifications.
  (multiple-value-bind (to-search search-specs) (stream->search-spec stream)
    (when debug
      (format *debug-io* "~&searching ~S~%      for ~S~&" to-search search-specs))
    (assert (validate-sorted-vector to-search) (to-search) "not sorted")
    (values (search-sorted-vector-with-search-vector to-search search-specs
                                                     :debug debug)
            to-search search-specs)))

(defun file->search-results (file &key (debug nil))
  ;; sort from a file
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (stream->search-results in :debug debug)))
```

### Using it

Given a file `/tmp/x.dat` with:

```
9
1
10
100
101
102
103
200
201
400
6
10
102
200
1
400
99
```

then:

```
  > (file->search-results "/tmp/x.dat" :debug t)
searching #(1 10 100 101 102 103 200 201 400)
      for #(10 102 200 1 400 99)
* 10:
          0          4          8
          0          2          3
          0          1          1
* 102:
          0          4          8
* 200:
          0          4          8
          5          6          8
* 1:
          0          4          8
          0          2          3
          0          1          1
          0          0          0
* 400:
          0          4          8
          5          6          8
          7          7          8
          8          8          8
* 99:
          0          4          8
          0          2          3
          0          1          1
          2          1          1
#(1 4 6 0 8 nil)
#(1 10 100 101 102 103 200 201 400)
#(10 102 200 1 400 99)
```

You can see that the last search failed (`99` is not in the vector).

Comment: Great answer but I think there is a `)` missing at the end of `stream->search-spec` and `SBCL` complains that `search` is already defined in package `CL`.

Comment: And it seems to me that `search-sorted-vector-with-search-vector` is missing.

Comment: @MartinBuchmann: sorry: I have fixed the missing things I hope (I have not tested `search-sorted-vector-with-search-vector` as I'd thrown away the buffer I originally wrote it all in, but it's OK I think).  Thank you for finding them!